# Rails: Active admin load user on every page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time I reload a page (a totally blank page as well) I get this:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

So Active Admin load the admin user 1 every time I reload the page. Is it normal? There is one way to load AFTER other sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this query runs every time to check if the current admin user is a valid and existing one. I'd never used Active Admin, but with [rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) is the same thing

Comment: Do you know how can I load admin AFTER other queries? Thank you

Comment: The first thing that it will do is check if the user is valid. There is no way to do this later. It will have to check before do anything